# file didn't received through as2

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have implemented as2 communication with Amazon using AS2secure running on Apache Linux instance.They have send the file to our AS2 server. I can see the logs with that information. We sent positive MDN as well. But file didn't stored/saved on my server. May I know what is the reason behind this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First guess would be file permissions.  The AS2Secure is running via the webserver, so if the web server can't write, neither can AS2Secure.